# yarn ios error str.replace is not a function

Tags: react-native, macos

in react native project, when yarn ios
below error is happen how can i solve

error str.replace is not a function.

yangseon-uui-MacBookPro:LearnReactNative yangseon-u$ yarn ios
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ react-native run-ios
warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
error str.replace is not a function.
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
at inlineString (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/build/errors.js:25:33)
at new CLIError (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/build/errors.js:13:11)
at getProjectInfo (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/tools/getProjectInfo.js:29:11)
at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:82:58)
at Command.handleAction (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:23)
at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:482:17)
at /Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:65
at Command._chainOrCall (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1177:12)
at Command._parseCommand (/Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:27)
at /Users/yangseon-u/LearnReactNative/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1081:27
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

remove node_modules and install yarn and upgrade but still it is happen...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

look in your project .replace and check the input parameters, one should receive undefined

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).